# How to get checkboxlist item value

Tags: c#, list, checkbox, webforms

This is how I am adding values and text to my checkboxlist in c#

```
private void populateFruitList() {
    string selectCommand = "SELECT FruitName, FruitID FROM Fruit_Crate";

    using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), selectCommand)) {
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ds;
        CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "FruitName";
        CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "FruitID";
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to get value but intellisence not helping,

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in CheckBoxList1.Items) {
    if(cb.Checked)
        myList.Add(cb.Value); // SAYS wrong Syntax
```

Can someone direct me to right syntax please?

Comment: What's the type of `myList`?

Comment: If it's a `List<string>` then surely `myList.Add(cb.Value.ToString());` would do it?

Comment: there is no "Value" in cb .... , even intellisense saying there is no such property

Comment: What if you change `Checkbox` to `ListItem` on your `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.

`CheckBoxList` does not contain `CheckBox` items (or shouldn't), it's a collection of [ListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx). It should look like this: -

```
foreach (ListItem cb in CheckBoxList1.Items) 
{
    if(cb.Selected)
    {
         myList.Add(cb.Value);
    }
}
```